# How to differentiate between softwares/bundles provisioned for a target in ACE

Tags: apache, osgi, target, gateway, agent

I have 2 bundles A and B, using Apache ACE I have provisioned these bundle to a target in following steps.

1. Provisioned A (having version 1.0.0) to the target
2. Provisioned B (having version 1.0.0) to the target
3. Provisioned B (having version 2.0.0) to the target (upgrade of previous version step 2)

When I access (http://localhost:8080/deployment/gatewayid/versions)

I get following result

1.0.0  
2.0.0  
3.0.0

How will the management agent figure out which version belongs to which software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the set of configured artifacts for a target changes, ACE will create a new version for a target. To actually see what is in a version, the management agent on the target needs to fetch the version. The deployment package you then get contains all the metadata you need (ie. a list of artifacts and their versions).

Answer (score 0):

When running in the same OSGi framework as your target bundles, you can use the [BundleContext](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html) to get to the bundles, and ask them for their installed versions. Something like,

```
for (Bundle b : bundleContext) {
    System.out.println("Found bundle " + b.getSymbolicName() + " in version " + b.getVersion());
}
```

If you also need to know whether this bundle has been installed from a deployment package, you can ask it for its `getLocation()`; this will start with `osgi-dp:`, as per the Deployment Admin spec.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I needed this information from Management Agent's perspective as I am developing a custom Management Agent.

Comment: Ah, right, I didn't catch that (could you update the question to clarify that?). What exactly do you want to know, the currently installed deployment version, or the versions of the bundles?

Comment: Updated the question. I want to know the bundle name and their version available for a particular target.

Comment: "For a particular target": do you mean you have code running in a target that needs this, or code running on the server that needs it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please let me know what the result of accessing (http://localhost:8080/deployment/gatewayid/versions)
i.e.
1.0.0 
2.0.0 
3.0.0

signify.
Also, don't we have any Rest API using which Management Agent can find out what software and their respective version have been provisioned for a target.

Comment: This discussion is getting a bit long; if you can make it into a crisp question (probably showing some code), you can try posting a new question. If there needs to be some discussion around this, feel free to move this discussion to the [ace user mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ace-users/) .